# Can't run nodeJS from Java

Tags: java, node.js, cmd, command

I'm trying to run a NodeJS script from a Java application but I'm getting an error.

Java code:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node --version");
 pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
 pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
 "node --version": CreateProcess error=2, Unable to find the specified 
 file
```

I tried using the solutions from StackOwerflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official documentation of ProcessBuilder (Java SE 8): 
[ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

> Each process builder manages these process attributes:
>
> - a command, a **list of strings** which signifies the external program file to be invoked and its arguments, if any. Which string lists represent a valid operating system command is system-dependent. For example, **it is common for each conceptual argument to be an element in this list**, but there are operating systems where programs are expected to tokenize command line strings themselves - on such a system a Java implementation might require commands to contain exactly two elements.

That means that you should put each argument as a separate string in the list like this:

```java
List<String> command = Arrays.asList("C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe", "--version");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
/* configure your process builder as you need */
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you just needed to specify the path to NodeJS:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe", "--version");
```

Comment: Don’t quote arguments.  Quoting arguments is for shells, not for direct execution of programs.  The first argument should be `"C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe"`.  No quote characters.